# Extracting multiple elements from within the name tag in KML

Tags: python, kml

I am trying to extract each of the components that are listed within the `<name> 703 , 705 , 2.0 /<name>`  tag in KML using Python.  `KML_Coord.py` will extract the first component=703, but will not extract the remaining 2 elements. I have included both an example fragment of the KML and KML_Coord.py.

**KML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>002MaPBs.kml</name>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0b00f7</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0b00f7</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>002MaPBs</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>937 ,         909 ,   2.000000</name>
            <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
            <description><![CDATA[<b>ID</b>: 
        9373 ,         909 ,   2.000000]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <coordinates>
                    -175.9011461110343,-25.83393837881608,0 -175.7293,-24.9121,0 -175.5085,-24.2871,0 -175.086,-23.3432,0 -174.5689,-21.9056,0 -174.2679,-20.6946,0 -173.9963,-19.5004,0 -173.8062,-18.4473,0 -173.7508,-17.6699,0 -173.8452,-16.6351,0 -174.4051,-15.9154,0 -175.4583302726206,-15.80931248642389,0 
                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>664 ,         660 ,   2.000000</name>
            <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
            <description><![CDATA[<b>ID</b>: 
         664 ,         660 ,   2.000000]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <coordinates>
                    144.9408,23.8301,0 143.0539,22.8135,0 143.9856,21.7793,0 144.6891,20.7105,0 145.3185,19.8239,0 145.6838,18.1952,0 145.6203,16.5074,0 145.4653,14.742,0 145.0452,13.4625,0 144.3875,12.0465,0 144.0193,11.312,0 
                </coordinates>
                <gx:altitudeMode>clampToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>703 ,         705 ,   2.000000</name>
            <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
            <description><![CDATA[<b>ID</b>: 
         703 ,         705 ,   2.000000]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <coordinates>
                    32.49561499731563,-46.93409975678188,0 34.1641,-42.8573,0 33.3476,-41.0566,0 36.0143,-35.1924,0 37.0452,-30.7158,0 37.0131,-25.8722,0 36.573,-20.9594,0 35.8065,-18.0845,0 34.8879,-13.092,0 34.6756,-9.526999999999999,0 32.0827,-7.375699999999999,0 29.2255,-4.1015,0 29.5543,-0.5662,0 29.7854,0.9777000000000001,0 31.8906,2.6335,0 31.74759999999999,3.4358,0 34.8159,5.2814,0 36.3579,3.2474,0 37.7376,6.312,0 39.7082,8.4687,0 42.29210808297798,11.8997691953729,0 
                </coordinates>
                <gx:altitudeMode>clampToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

**KML_Coord.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

def main():
  # KML parse
    tree = ET.parse('input.kml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    
  # Identify default namespace
    namespace = re.match('\{(.*?)\}kml', root.tag).group(1)
    ns = {'def': namespace}
    
  # Define coordinates RegEx
    coord_ex = '(-?\d+\.\d+),'
    heig_ex = '(\d+)'
    regex = coord_ex + coord_ex + heig_ex
    
  # Create output files (overwrite if already exist)
    with open('output_pins.txt','w') as out_pin,  \
         open('output_paths.txt','w') as out_pat, \
         open('output_polygons.txt','w') as out_pol:
      
      # Add headers
        out_pin.write('Pin Name,Latitude,Longitude,Height\n')
        out_pat.write('Pin Name,Pin_#,Latitude,Longitude,Height\n')
        out_pol.write('Pin Name,Pin_#,Latitude,Longitude,Height\n')

      # Find coordinates
        for i in root.findall('.//def:Placemark', ns):
          name = i.find('def:name', ns).text
          coord = i.find('.//def:coordinates', ns)
        # Check for placeless placemark     
          if not coord is None:
              coord = coord.text.strip()
              coord = re.findall(regex, coord)
            # Save data
              pin = 0
              for (long, lat, heig) in coord:
                  pin += 1
                  if i.find('.//def:Point', ns):
                      out_pin.write(f'{name},{lat},{long},{heig}\n')
                  elif i.find('.//def:LineString', ns):   
                      out_pat.write(f'{name},pin_{pin},{lat},{long},{heig}\n')
                  elif i.find('.//def:Polygon', ns):   
                      out_pol.write(f'{name},pin_{pin},{lat},{long},{heig}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you trim your question down to just the minimum needed to show your problem? We don't need to see the whole KML - just the element and it's parent and just the code processing the extracted name.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your examples I get a output_paths.txt file with 3 lines, one for each . I also added debug print statements, and I would think your code runs just as you expect it to run.